# How do i pass small Case parameter to query

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $this->db->select("ID");
    $whereCondition = array('CITY' =>$this->db->escape_like_str($cityName) , 'STATUS'=>'A');
    $this->db->where($whereCondition);
```

In the above code snippet want to perform where codition operation in small case letter

My DB Field Value is "Mumbai" and Actual Value "Mumbai" 
want to convert it to mumbai mumbai.

How do i do this using code ignitor

Comment: are you using MYSQL or *ANOTHER* DB?

Answer (score 0):

You could run your 'string' through the PHP function `strtolower()`

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Example:

```
<?php
$str = "Mary Had A Little Lamb and She LOVED It So";
$str = strtolower($str);
echo $str; // Prints mary had a little lamb and she loved it so
?>
```

**EDIT**

In case I read it wrong, as I re-read it now, you want your DB value to be compared? I do believe that mysql is case insensitive by default. So your Mumbai will equal mubmai when compared `Mumbai = mumbai` in mysql.

Comment: what about DB field value. otherwise join will return only small case records. I want to convert DB field and paramter both value at the time of query execution

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't have an API... what are you asking now?

Comment: As @Jakub mentioned, you want to use a collation that ends with _ci (case insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your question right. I suggest the following:

For the column name:

ALTER TABLE table_name
      RENAME column_name TO LOWER(column_name);

For the field value:

UPDATE table_name
SET Column_name=LOWER(Column_name)
WHERE Column_name LIKE 'Mumbai';

Comment: this is not really needed if @OP uses MYSQL with `_ci` collation